# Facebook v7.1.0 share not working right

Tags: c#, android, facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm having a really hard time with this new sdk in unity. Now, the share function is not working as expected. When I use the share function it shares the game page instead of a sentence.

What am i doing wrong?

Share Function Call

```
Share( new System.Uri("https://www.facebook.com/v8orsflyingrat?fref=ts"),
                                   "V8ors - Flying Rat",
                                   "Check my Highscore",
                                   "I just got " + GameManager.instance.CurrPoints + " points on V8ors - Flying Rat  #v8orsflyingrat",
                                   new System.Uri("http://media.moddb.com/images/games/1/41/40326/INDIE_DB_PreviewImage.jpg"));
```

Share Function

```
Share (System.Uri link, string linkName, string linkCaption, string linkDescription, System.Uri picture) 
{
FB.FeedShare(link: link,
            linkName: linkName,
            linkCaption: linkCaption,
            linkDescription: linkDescription,
            picture: picture);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never try FB.FeedShare(). But, if you don't mind, you can try FB.ShareLink().

```
FB.ShareLink(url,
             title,
             msg,
             pictureUrl,
             callback);
```

Because I found the error in the previous sdk version, I don't like to use prefix when passing variable since then.

If you want to post only feed with message, I think you can use [/feed/](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/feed) in graph-api with [FB.API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.API).

```
FB.API("me/feed", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, callback, formdata);
```

Comment: Well, tried it and the exat same result. It publish what I type in the share form but instead of having my description it has the game page with the like button.

Comment: @RúbenRocha  Sorry, I didn't read well enough. Please check a link in my answer.

Comment: Well, this doesn't solve the share problem since it doesn't have interface but it works, so thanks :D

note - I find it very difficult to dig through facebook documentation. It's just me or is it that bad documented?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you are omitting the toId parameter from the FeedShare call - even if it is defaulting to the user and not sharing to someone else's page, you have to include it, as the method is not overloaded.

Try putting string.Empty as the first parameter in your call...